# Using WebAssembly with Jest and Webpack

Tags: webpack, jestjs, webassembly

I've got a POC project where I'm trying to test a function that depends on a webassembly module, but for some reason I don't understand it's not loading it correctly during the test.

The webassembly module(rust) is very simple.  It exposes a single method that takes two numbers and adds them together. It's prepared by wasm-pack(v0.11) with `--target bundler` and I've got a simple integration with this in my webpack config using wasm-pack-plugin so that this module is watched and built should the rust code change.  In my toplevel project.json I've got this module as a filesystem-based dependency:
 `"rust_module": "file:src/rust_module/pkg"`

In my main "production" code(typescript), I've got a simple import and a simple usage:

```
import * as r_m from 'rust_module'

export function addFiveSix(){
    return r_m.add(5,6)
}
```

In my webpack(v5) config, I'm using the ecmascript module "experiment" and when I execute `webpack bundle`, it  executes without any error.

However, when I execute Jest(`cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest`) to run a simple test of `adddFiveSix`, it errors out:

```
spike_jest_wasm\src\rust_module\pkg\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import * as wasm from "./index_bg.wasm";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I'm sort of assuming that Jest does it's own in-memory rollup of all the linked code as it bootstraps itself(using babel and whatnot)...and that it isn't capable of what webpack is doing.  Is this what's happening?  Is there a way around this?  Is there a way I can use the webpack bundle as the input of jest?

Fyi, I've got this project in a [public bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/mwkohout/webpack-wasm-jest-poc/src/main/) if this ends up being useful.

Comment: "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". Maybe, you need a configurate jest for es6 imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't tell Jest to transform the rust_module.

Adding

```
 transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!(rust_module))/"],
 modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/*']
```

where `rust_module` is the name of the module solved my problem.